# C# WinForms ComboBox - Selecting just the Value from an Object

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I just need a little confirmation ...

I'm filling my combobox like so:

```
myCombo.Items.Add(new ComboBoxInt32Data("Red", 0));
myCombo.Items.Add(new ComboBoxInt32Data("Green", 1));
myCombo.Items.Add(new ComboBoxInt32Data("Yellow", 2));
myCombo.Items.Add(new ComboBoxInt32Data("Blue", 3));
```

Now, when I'm retrieving values from the database table, I have just the integer value.

My overriden Equals looks exactly as how msdn [suggests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ComboBoxInt32Data data = obj as ComboBoxInt32Data;
    if ((object)data == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return (m_Name.ToUpper() == data.Name.ToUpper() && m_Value == data.Value);
}
```

But, as I mentioned, I have just the value.  I don't want to have to go and do the following:

```
Int32 DatabaseValue = SomeFunctionThatRetrivedMeThisIntValueFromDB();
string TheValueName = SomeFunctionThatDoesALookUpToGetTheName(DatabaseValue);
myCombo.SelectedIndex = myCombo.Items.IndexOf(new ComboBoxInt32Data(TheValueName, DatabaseValue));
```

I'd rather just do the following:

```
myCombo.SelectedIndex = myCombo.Items.IndexOf(SomeFunctionThatRetrivedMeThisIntValueFromDB());
```

So, my confirmation is, is it OK (as in, is it an acceptable best practice) to do the following in my Equals (look for 'added this'):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // added this
    if (obj is Int32)
    {
        Int32 value = (Int32)obj;
        return m_Value == value;
    }

    ComboBoxInt32Data data = obj as ComboBoxInt32Data;
    if ((object)data == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return (m_Name.ToUpper() == data.Name.ToUpper() && m_Value == data.Value);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to override `Equal` and `GetHashCode`, the easy way is to *cast* to `ComboBoxInt32Data` and use LINQ to select item:

```
myCombo.SelectedItem =  myCombo.Items.Cast<ComboBoxInt32Data>()
                          .SingleOrDefault(item => item.Value == databaseValue);
```

Comment: And this is exactly why I asked the question.  That looks cool.  It seems I don't have to modify the Equals as I did, and can instead, search on it like so.  (comparing the two in my brain as I speak).  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Cuong +1 for an elegant solution, but wouldn't you agree the overall solution is not the best solution? Take a look at my answer and tell me if I'm off base.

Comment: @Mike - yeah, I'd like to see a discussion, as I mentioned we avoid databind'ing combos.  Maybe that was a bad decision.

Comment: @CuongLe, thanks. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't off base there!

Comment: I'm not sure if this truly answered my question (i was more interested in 'best practices' of overriding Equals), but it was a cool little trick.  Green check-mark for you!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding your need, or if I'm really seeing what I think I'm seeing, but I think I can simplify your solution quite a bit. Let's take a very simple example - I have a table named `FooTypes` and it contains data like this:

```
Id        Name                Order
-----------------------------------
1         Type 1              1
2         Type 2              2
3         Type 3              4
4         Type 4              3
```

And now I want to load a combo box with that data so I'm going to do something like this**:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("some connection string");
var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Name FROM FooTypes ORDER BY Order", conn);
var dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

comboBox.ValueMember = "Id";
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox.DataSource = dt;

comboBox.SelectedValue = SomeFunctionThatRetrivedMeThisIntValueFromDB();
```

** Bear in mind this is an example so you may grab the connection and stuff from somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe this is just hesitation from years ago coding experience (and potential issues discovered then that now unfairly stop us from doing it now), but for some reason a "best practice" here where I work is to not databind combos.  Awesome example though, and thanks for the answer!

Comment: @JustLooking, I'm sorry that they are against it, but I would love to hear the argument against data binding. I say that because I too have been writing software for more than twelve years and haven't found a reason against it yet. Thanks!!

Comment: @CuongLe: are you speaking of custom painting the items in the list?

Comment: @Mike: yes, I believe Red, Green, Yellow, Blue is displayed in UI? ah, I got it, you use Type 1...

Comment: @CuongLe: that's right, you would just change those values to whatever made sense for the lookup you were providing ... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
var indexToSelect = SomeFunctionThatRetrievedMeThisIntValueFromDB();
var selectedItem = myCombo.Items
    .Cast<ComboBoxInt32Data>()
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Value == indexToSelect);
if (selectedItem != null)
{
    myCombo.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
}
```

Comment: Awesome answer and similar to Cuong Le.  I'll look at both.  Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.